# Run .sh file from cygwin on windows 7

Tags: windows, bash, shell, cygwin

I am trying to run `.sh` file from `cygwin` on windows 7

My **dumdb.sh** file content

```
#!/bin/bash
for database in $(mysql -e "show databases"|awk -F " " '{print $1}') do
    mysqldump -u root -h localhost -p $database > $database.sql
done
```

On running this command

```
$ sh dumpdb.sh
```

m getting following error

```
bash: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `mysqldump'
bash: line 3: `mysqldump $database > $database.sql'
```

Where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `;` before `do`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for database in $(mysql -e "show databases"|awk -F " " '{print $1}') ; do
    mysqldump $database > $database.sql
done
```

Comment: Thanks, but now m getting this error `dumpdb.sh: line 4: mysql: command not found`

Comment: It sounds like you don't have `mysql` installed, or at least it can't be found in your `PATH`.

Comment: Yeah thanx, I added the mysql path and the errors are gone, but the shell script is not working as expected. Is it correct? (it is to dump all database in separate files). Got it from [here](http://thecodecave.com/2010/12/11/how-to-dump-or-backup-all-mysql-databases-to-separate-files/).

Comment: You should probably first test `mysqldump` on its own with a single database to see if it is doing what you want.