# How to run Bash shell script on Windows?

Tags: mysql, windows, bash, shell

I got a shell file from my friend and I have no idea how to execute it. Can anyone please help me in executing it? I'm using Windows platform.
This is the content of my shell file. The file name is `db_update.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Adding tables and data to the DB
mysql csespn -h "localhost" -u "root" -p < "create_tables.sql"

echo Adding base data to the DB
mysql csespn -h "localhost" -u "root" -p < "seed_basedata.sql"

echo Sample data to the DB for development purposes
mysql csespn -h "localhost" -u "root" -p < "seed_sampledata.sql"
```

Comment: If you rename the file from `db_update.sh` to `db_update.bat` it will probably work as is (provided that you have MySQL installed and the database `csespn` exists).

Comment: @mustaccio I think the hashbang line (`#!/bin/bash`) has to be removed as Windows shell does not use `#` for comments, AFAIK. But otherwise I agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to have the create_tables.sql, seed_basedata.sql, seed_samledata.sql in the same folder as your script.

then having mysql installed is mandatory, if you don't have you can install[WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/) , it contains everything you need including mysql...

the .bat file won't probably work, you can find how to convert shell script to bat file, or you can create another one which does the same thing easily.

Answer (score 1):

One way is installing third-party tools such as [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com). Shell is a UNIX operating system script.

Comment: In general yes, you need a shell to execute shell scripts and one can be made to run on Windows via Cygwin, but in this case running the script through Cygwin is an overkill with serious side-effects. You’ll use different MySQL version then, e.g.

Comment: Shell is a command interpreter, script is a sequence of commands for a shell.

Comment: See also this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520719/run-sh-file-from-cygwin-on-windows-7?rq=1.